# Update configurable products in Magento via CSV

Tags: magento, csv, import, configurable

I'm making a Magento webshop which uses dataflow import of CSV to create products automatically from our seperate stock management system.

When the products is imported for the first time, there is no errors and the import process is working perfectly. However - when I import them again, to update stock, description etc., the configurable products gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '875-135' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'
```

Is there any way to make it overwrite correctly?